# Copy constructor- calling function by value twice with same variable caused problems?

Tags: c++, copy-constructor

I was pointed to the following article:

http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/78946/C-Copy-Constructor-in-depth

and we have the code:

```
class string
{
    // constructor
    string(char* aStr)
    {
        str = new char[sizeof(aStr)];
        strcpy (str,aStr);
    }

    // destructor
    ~string() 
    {
        del str;
    }

    char *getChars(){ return str; }
    char* str;
};


void function (string str)
{
    // do something 
}


void main ()
{
    string str("hello");
    function(str);
    function(str); // program crashes
}
```

I do not understand why in `main`, there would be a problem with the second call to `function`? Surely when `str` is passed in to the first call, this would only be a copy of `str` and therefore anything done to `str` within `function` would not affect the variable `str` declared in `main`?

Comment: [Rule of Three](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_(C%2B%2B_programming)); it should crash with just one call.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is The Rule of Three?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three)

Comment: The rule of three seems like a popular theme tonight.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default copy constructor does a bit-by-bit copy of the object. In other words, the pointer member is copied, but not the object it points to. Pointers in both objects will point to the same object **if you use the default constructor and do only a shallow copy**.

**Specific to your question:**

The first time you call `function(str)` everything works properly, when the function ends, the input argument on the stack is destroyed (which is a copy of `str`, but using the default copy constructor its pointers point to the same location as the original object), and its destructor will be called deleting the object pointed by the pointer.

The second time you call `function(str)`, and when the function ends, the destructor will try now to free the address pointed by the pointer in `str`, and crash.

**To avoid such problems, you should define your own copy constructor, which properly copies the objects not only the pointers, performing a deep copy.**

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that the `str` member in your `string` class is a pointer.  This means that when a copy of your string is created, the value of this pointer is copied, but the value of a pointer is just a memory location.  So when you call `function(str)`, it is modifying the memory at that location, even though it isn't modifying the value of your pointer.

Answer (score 1):

By default C++ only knows how to do a shallow copy of data with a default copy constructor. So, yes, the first call to `function` does make a "copy" of `str`, but this copy isn't much of a copy, since what got copied was the `char*` instance data of the string class. Ie, C++ is just copying an address over, but isn't smart enough to actually allocate space for a new string and copy the contents over. You'd have to do that yourself with a custom copy constructor.

Answer (score 0):

The constructor for `str` doesn't allocate enough bytes for the subsequent call to `strcpy`. After that, all bets are off. Once that's fixed, write a proper copy constructor and copy assignment operator.